# Showing a sequence converges in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

I'm studying for a test on Monday and am going through some supplementary problems. These problems do not come with solutions provided but I still think they are very good practice.

Suppose sequence $X_n$ satisfies:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n} \mathbb{E}[|X_n - c|^\alpha ] = 0
\end{align}
where $\alpha > 0$. Show that the sequence converges to $c$ in probability.

This is a type of problem I have never seen before. I am sort-of familiar with convergence in probability problems but I have never seen one that takes the limit of an expectation.

I know for $X_n$ to converge in probability to some value $a$ we must have:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n} \mathbb{P}(|X_n - a| > \epsilon) = 0
\end{align}

and this looks very similar, but the expectation is still throwing me off.

Any tips on how to begin? I will try my best to understand but again these problems were not assigned at any time during my course so far and so I am not even sure if the proper ways to deal with this problem were covered in class.

Also, why is it important to note that $\alpha$ is positive?

Comment: Suppose it doesn't converge in probability to $c$. Use the definition of this statement to get $\epsilon,\delta>0$ and a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ with $P(|X_{n_k}-c|>\epsilon)>\delta$. Argue that $E[|X_{n_k}-c|^\alpha]$ cannot go to zero.

Comment: @Ian, I'm on it!

Comment: Alternatively, Markov's inequality applied to $|X_n - c|^\alpha$ will do the trick with slightly less ink.

Comment: @stochasticboy321, wow. I didn't think of it but it absolutely works since Markov's inequality will give me an upper bound in terms of this term's expectation which we know converges to $0$ thus the term itself must converge to $0$ since it is bounded on top by $0$

Comment: @Ian I am very curious about your approach as well. Is that just a proof of the contrapositive? I've just solved it using stochasticboy321's method and it is very clean. However, I still want to try and solve it your way.

Comment: @DavidSouth What I suggested is basically a way to prove Markov's inequality.